# Remove file types from the .gitignore file

Tags: xcode, git, github, gitignore

I accidentally added .h files to the gitignore file and need help deleting that file type off of the ignore list. My xcode builds are not finding necessary files because of them being removed.

I am fine with removing the file type or deleting the whole thing. I am on a mac.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is somewhat misleading as ignoring a file just stops it being tracked by git, it doesn't delete it as you imply.  Unless, of course, you are talking about the cloned version of the repo on a different machine?  Please clarify.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have a few file types on the gitignore list. These files are not downloaded when I sync or download a zip file from my github online to the local copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the file named `.gitignore` with any text editor and remove the lines that you would like to stop ignoring.

Comment: I just couldn't find it in any of my files. I searched in all files on my mac

Comment: You will probably not be able to see it using the UI.  From the command line, try, `cat .gitignore` and you will be able to see the file's contents

Comment: It says no such file or directory. I know for a fact there is one though

Comment: @BradTidwell The `.gitignore` file may be in your home directory (a global file), or in any directory within the git repo in question. If it is located at the root of the repo, it will affect the whole thing, if it's further in, it only affects the directory where it is located and any subdirectories deeper from that point. Try: `cd /path/to/repo; find . -name .gitignore -print`

Comment: That has shown the locations of where they should be, for my different projects, but when i follow the path it takes me to nothing.

Comment: Also, when I go in my GitHub Windows, and right click the ignore file, and do show in finder, It leads me to a seemingly appropriate folder but no ignore file.